# DTO not being passed (spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a signup page for my website and it submits fine. When the email already exists I expect it to recreate the values in the first name, last name, email, and country. The problem is that it displays the text just fine, however that values are not re-created.

My jsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="cssPath" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="${cssPath}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grayDiv divCenter">
        <h1 th:text="${title}" class="titleTextCenter"></h1>
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="error" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="color" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
        <h2 th:text="${error}" class="textCenter text" th:style="'color: '+${color}+';'"></h2>
        <div>
            <form th:action="@{/api/v2/signup/register}" method="post" class="signup" style="width:100%;" th:object="${account}" th:style="'width:100%;'">
                <div>
                    <input th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="formTextBox" style="width: 48%; float: left;" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" required name="fname">
                    <input th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="formTextBox" style="width: 48%; float: right;" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" required name="lname" >
                </div>
                <br>
                <input th:field="*{email}" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="formTextBox"  required name="email" >
                <div style="width: 100%;">
                    <select th:field="*{country}" name="country" id="country" class="formTextBox formSelect" required>
                        <option value="" disabled hidden style="color: #8e8e8e;">Country</option>
                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                        <option value="INDIA">India</option>
                        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="EU">European Union</option>
                        <option value="AUS">Australia</option>
                        <option value="JAPAN">Japan</option>
                        <option value="CANADA">Canada</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input th:field="*{password}" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="formTextBox" required name="pwrd" id="pwrd" >
                <input th:field="*{confirmPassword}" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="formTextBox" required name="cpwrd" id="cpwrd">
                <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my @GetMapping for the signup page:

```
  @GetMapping("/signup")
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public String signup(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "color", required = false) String color, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, AccountDTO dto) {
    log.info(dto.getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("account", new AccountDTO());
    model.addAttribute("cssPath", "../css/index.css");
    model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome To Expense Tracker");
    model.addAttribute("error", error == null ?  "." : error);
    model.addAttribute("color", color == null ? Color.LIGHT_BACKGROUND.getColor() : color);
    return "signup/signup";
}
```

And finally this is my register api:

```
  @PostMapping("register")
public ModelAndView register(@ModelAttribute("account") @Valid AccountDTO dto, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("Registering user");
    log.info("email: " + dto.getEmail());
        try {
            log.info("Checking if user exists");
            Account account = service.register(dto);
            String url = request.getContextPath();
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new RegistrationCompleteEvent(account, request.getLocale(), url));
            forceLogin(request, dto.getEmail(), dto.getPassword());
            log.info("redirecting to verification");
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/verification", "account", new AccountDTO(dto.getFirstName(), dto.getLastName(), dto.getEmail(), dto.getCountry(), dto.getPassword(), dto.getConfirmPassword()));
            mav.addObject("cssPath", "../../../../css/index.css");
            return mav;
        } catch (UserExistsException eaeEx) {
            log.warn("User exists, redirecting back to signup page DTO: " + dto.getEmail());
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("redirect:/signup", "account", new AccountDTO(dto.getFirstName(), dto.getLastName(), dto.getEmail(), dto.getCountry(), dto.getPassword(), dto.getConfirmPassword()));
            model.addObject("error", "This email already exists!");
            model.addObject("color", Color.ERROR.getColor());
            return model;
        }
}
```

The log shows that its passing the email correctly, but in the /signup it says that its null

Comment: From the `register()` method, the `dto` probably needs to be added to the returned `ModelAndView` so that `"*{firstName}"` can discover the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use RedirectAttributes

```
@PostMapping("register")
public ModelAndView register(@ModelAttribute("account") @Valid AccountDTO dto, RedirectAttributes attr, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("Registering user");
    log.info("email: " + dto.getEmail());
        try {
            log.info("Checking if user exists");
            Account account = service.register(dto);
            String url = request.getContextPath();
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new RegistrationCompleteEvent(account, request.getLocale(), url));
            forceLogin(request, dto.getEmail(), dto.getPassword());
            log.info("redirecting to verification");
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/verification", "account", new AccountDTO(dto.getFirstName(), dto.getLastName(), dto.getEmail(), dto.getCountry(), dto.getPassword(), dto.getConfirmPassword()));
            mav.addObject("cssPath", "../../../../css/index.css");
            return mav;
        } catch (UserExistsException eaeEx) {
            log.warn("User exists, redirecting back to signup page DTO: " + dto.getEmail());
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("redirect:/signup");
            attr.addFlashAttribute("account", new AccountDTO(dto.getFirstName(), dto.getLastName(), dto.getEmail(), dto.getCountry(), dto.getPassword(), dto.getConfirmPassword());
            attr.addFlashAttribute("error", "This email already exists!");
            attr.addFlashAttribute("color", Color.ERROR.getColor());
            return model;
        }
}
```

and receive the account dto

```
  @GetMapping("/signup")
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public String signup(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "color", required = false) String color, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @ModelAttribute("account") AccountDTO dto) {
    log.info(dto.getEmail());
    if (dto == null) {
      model.addAttribute("account", new AccountDTO());
    } else {
      model.addAttribute("account", dto);
    }
    
    model.addAttribute("cssPath", "../css/index.css");
    model.addAttribute("title", "Welcome To Expense Tracker");
    model.addAttribute("error", error == null ?  "." : error);
    model.addAttribute("color", color == null ? Color.LIGHT_BACKGROUND.getColor() : color);
    return "signup/signup";
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it only seems to pass the cssPath and the title back
Edit: I think i know why the DTO is not being passed back. In the @GetMapping for /signup its reverting everything even though I put null checks in them. This means that my DTO and error and color is null. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: you can check dto is null or not